# Should i trigger a login or signup popup for "registered only features"?

Tags: user-expectation, login, registration, conversion-rate

I have a SPA which allows the user to act as an anonymous or as registered / logged in user (Free/Paying).

For better converasion rate & UX - what is the best flow? what is the user expectation in that case (while I don't want to tired those who pays and just need to login)

User clicks on feature which available only for registered users:
1. Show Signup popup
or
2. Show Login popup

Thank you!

Comment: this is a "you'll have to test by yourself" question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for the Login feature. If your users are required to login for these features, it is a logical step to supply this as a first step. Naturally the option for signing up should be clear as well. I would probably go for something like a tab system within a modal, one for logging in, signing up second.

Having said that, the user should not be surprised with a modal. By separating the features with a different visual layout, the user should be able to see which features will require a login before being confronted with a login/sign up screen.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have one form which accomplishes both? User enters their email and password, if the email is not registered, reveal the remainder of the signup form, if they are registered, log them in.

Comment: My Signup page has extra information that needs to be provided such as discount code, companies registration, etc... so merging between them will trigger an entire flow change which I don't know if I want to go there.
Thank you for your opinion & comment.